# Looking For a Google AdWords Template for Adobe Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, cs5, google

Does anyone know where I can get an Adobe Illustrator CS5 template for Google AdWords? There is one on the web through Adobe but it's the old sizes (which are off by just a couple pixels) and it's optimized for CS4.

I am also posting this in the Graphic Design Stack Exchange (wasn't sure which it really belonged in. Sorry if this is the wrong forum.)

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a template, there is a thorough list of the required specs here: http://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it for CS5...[link here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/652561/share-with-the-internets/adwords-illustrator-cs5.zip). Enjoy! Let me know if there's a way I can improve it.

Comment: +1 for doing the work (and doing it nicely) while scoring what might be the easiest bounty ever.

Comment: Hey, gotta be a bit opportunistic. I was surprised no one else went for this one!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Brendan's work, I added the newest Google ad format and bumped it to CS6. [Link here](https://googledrive.com/host/0B7Ah8xiDENMxWlBnbF94ZXhxZGM/Google%20AdWords%20Template%20for%20Illustrator%20CS6.ai.zip)!